# One-Time Script TimeOut for Large Data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am using WP to run a coupon website. I have a custom theme which creates custom post type “Coupons” & custom taxonomy “Stores” and “Categories” for these coupons. I have a huge amount of data on this site (5K stores and almost 50K coupons associated with it). So sometimes I have a requirement of extracting some specific data from these coupons.

I wrote a “one-time script” which I place in my theme’s functions.php and run it using parameters in the URL. Example:
This is the code I add in functions.php

```
if ( isset($_GET['linkupdate']) ) {
    add_action('init', 'link_update', 10);
}
function link_update() {
  // actions to perform
// actions to perform
   die;
}
```

Then I run this with “www.sitename.com/?linkupdate” URL.

This is running perfectly for small to medium amount of data (for data of 1K stores) but when it comes to getting data of more than 2-3K stores the script times out.

I tried using `set_time_limit(0);` before my code starts executing but it is not helping. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a mistake to run reporting style task on a production site. you can live with it for a "small" site, but the bigger the site is, you will run against the limitation of webserver architecture, language architecture, and framework architecture, which neither of them was designed to handle CPU and memory stressful tasks.

One obvious way to break out of the limitations, is to download the DB and run whatever you want on a local PC which is most likely much more powerful than your web server.

If for whatever reason it is hard to do, your best bet is probably to integrate the report generation with WP-CLI, and run it from the server's command line (you do have ssh access, right? ;) ) this way you avoid the webserver related limitation, but still might be problematic if it uses lots of memory and CPU, so you might need to structure your code smartly, breaking generation into chunks instead of trying to do it in one go.

.... and breaking into chunks can be achieved by using some sort of progressive generation with ajax. Can it be done in your case? depends if you can break the whole operation into mostly independent chunks.